# How to fix error reset link formatting when reset password erpnext?

Tags: erpnext, frappe

Hello… I have error reset link when reset password for user like this:

> http://xxxxx.xxxxxx.com,xxxxx.xxxxxx.com:8000/update-password?key=MpqDCOxDO7vEZUCHi5F8rfSHeIgzBLyo

The link is duplicated, contains comma and port number !
It should like this:

> https://xxxxx.xxxxxx.com/update-password?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Any kind of help please?

Answer (score 0):

This problem will resolve if you set your host_name in site_config.json file of that particular site

Comment: I have set my hostname but even after that I am getting reset link in email like:
"http://%27XXX.com%27:8000/update-password?key=YYYYYYYY"